# How do I return location.hostname without the trailing slash?

Tags: javascript, string, data-manipulation, window.location, trailing-slash

How do I return the string `example.com` using JavaScript if the input is `https://example.com/page.html?query=string`?

Right now, if I use `window.location.hostname` – or `location.hostname` – the return value is
`example.com`***`/`***, but I want
`example.com`, without the trailing slash.

---

This question is similar to @[r1853](https://stackoverflow.com/u/3914662)’s “[How to remove trailing slash from window.location.pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185383)”, but because JavaScript provides many ways to grab parts of a URI (`location.hostname`, `location.host`, `location.href`), and because wellformed URIs are a closed class, I had assumed there was a less expensive option than using a regular expression to remove trailing slashes from them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove trailing slash from window.location.pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185383/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-from-window-location-pathname)

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185383/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-from-window-location-pathname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your `window.location.hostname` into a variable:

```js
let hostname = window.location.hostname;
```

and then use `substring` to remove the last character (which will be that trailing slash)

```js
hostname = hostname.substring(0, hostname.length - 1);
```

If you want to make sure that the last character is actually a `/`, then you can use an `if` statement:

```js
if (hostname.charAt(hostname.length - 1) == '/') {
  hostname = hostname.substring(0, hostname.length - 1)
}
```

Comment: Is there no other mechanism in JavaScript for that part of the URI, like maybe `window.location.hostnamebeforetheslash` or something?

Comment: Not that I know of